# The boundedness of $L_1$ norm $\|(I+A)^{-1}\|_1$ if both $\|A\|_1$ and $\|A^{-1}\|_1$ are bounded

Tags: linear-algebra

> Assume that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, both  $\|A\|_1$ and $\|A^{-1}\|_1$ are uniformly bounded as $N \to \infty.$ Here $\| \cdot \|_1$ is the induced $L_1$ Norm.
> Prove that there exists a constant $\kappa > 0$ such that
> $$\|(I_N+A)^{-1}\|_1 \leq \kappa $$ as $N \to \infty.$
> Else show a counterexample.

I attempted to demonstrate that the boundedness of $\|(I_N+A)^{-1}\|_1$ can be proven using the definition of $\| \cdot \|_1$ as follows

$$ \|(I_N + A)^{-1} \|_1 = \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{ \|(I_N + A)^{-1} x\|_1 }{\|x\|_1} = \sup_{z \neq 0} \frac{ \|z\|_1 }{\|(I_N+A)z\|_1} \leq \sup_{z \neq 0} \frac{ \|z\|_1 }{|\|Az\|_1 - \|z\|_1|} = \sup_{z \neq 0} \frac{1}{ \Big| \frac{\|Az\|_1}{\|z\|_1} - 1 \Big| } $$

However, it seems possible that $\inf_{z} \Big|\frac{\|Az\|_1}{\|z\|_1} - 1 \Big|=0$, so I doubt this proof is wrong.

But intuitively, $(I_N + A)^{-1}$ seems to be smaller than $A^{-1}$, and when we consider $L_2$ norm, it is easy to find that $\|(I_N + A)^{-1}\|_2 \leq 1$, so I guess the boundedness still holds when we consider $L_1$ norm.

Any guidance on how to tackle this problem? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hint: what do the conditions say about the eigenvalues of $A$ and what are the eigenvalues of $I_N + A$.

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain it a bit more clearly?

Comment: Your matrix is Hermitian, right? Then you can decompose it via $A = UDU^*$, where $U$ is unitary. Notice that $\|U\|_1 \leq 1$ and $\|U^*\|_1 \leq 1$, so in the end you just need to bound the eigenvalues of $(I + A)^{-1}$. But, please clarify if $A$ is Hermitian.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes, but I think the unitary matrix $U$ could have a large L1 norm. For example, consider setting the first column of $U$ to be $N^{-1/2}*(1, 1, ..., 1)$, then the column sum is $\sqrt{N}$

Comment: Ah, good point. I completely overlooked that. Still, if one can show that the 1-norms of these matrices are uniformly bounded, then the problem is solved.

Comment: Define $A_N \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ to be ${(A_N)}_{ij} =  
\begin{cases}
  -1 + \frac{1}{N} \text{ if i = j}\\
  0 \text{ i \neq j}
\end{cases}$,

 It follows that ${A_N}^{-1}=  
\begin{cases}
  \frac{N}{1-N} \text{ if i = j}\\
  0 \text{ if } i \neq j
\end{cases}$

If I'm not mistaken, both $\left|\left|A_N \right|\right|_1 \text{ and } \left|\left|{A_N}^{-1} \right|\right|_1\leq \frac{N} {N -1} \text{, but} \left|\left| (1 + A_N)^{-1} \right|\right|_1 \ge N$

Comment: @Catriel $A_N$ is not positive definite then.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: The answer below seems correct ?

Answer (score 2):

$$||(I+A^{-1})||$$ is finite iff $$\inf_{z:||z||_1 = 1} ||(I+A)z||_1 > 0.$$
Suppose not, $(I+A)z_n \rightarrow 0 \implies ||(I+A)z_n||_1 \leq \epsilon_N \implies Az_n  =  -z_n + v_{\epsilon_N}$ implies $z_n^TAz_n < 0$ for all $n \geq M$, where $||v_{\epsilon_N}||_1<\epsilon_N$ a contradiction to positive definiteness.
Hence $$\inf_{z:||z||_1 = 1} ||(I+A)z||_1 = \epsilon_N/2.$$ for some $\epsilon_N>0$. Suppose $\epsilon_N \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$ then for the contradction to fail you must have,
$$Az_n  =  -z_n + v_{\epsilon_N}$$
with $||z_n||_2 < ||v_{\epsilon_N}||_2 < ||v_{\epsilon_N}||_1 < \epsilon_N$.

Hence $$z_n^TAz_n  = -||z_n||_2^2+<z_n,v_{\epsilon_N}>$$
$$\frac{z_n^TAz_n}{||z_n||_2^2}  = -1+\frac{<z_n,v_{\epsilon_N}>}{||z_n||_2^2}$$
$$\frac{z_n^TAz_n}{||z_n||_2^2}  \leq -1+\frac{||v_{\epsilon_N}||_2}{||z_n||_2}$$
$$\frac{z_n^TAz_n}{||z_n||_2^2}  \leq -1+\frac{\epsilon_N}{||z_n||_2}$$
$$\lambda_{\min}(A)  \leq -1+\frac{2}{||z_n||_2 ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1}$$
From above derivation constant $2$ can be reduced and be made $1$ and and we get
$$\lambda_{\min}(A)  \leq -1+\frac{1}{||z_n||_2 ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1}$$

Hence,
$$\frac{1}{||z_n||_2 ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1} \geq 1$$
$$||z_n||_2 ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1 \leq 1.$$
$$||z^*||_2 ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1 \leq 1.$$
where $z^*$ achieves $\inf_{z:||z||_1 = 1} ||(I+A)z||_1$ and $||z^*||_1 = 1$.
Now $z^* = (I+A)^{-1}x^*$ where $x^*$ achieves $||(I+A)^{-1}||_1$ and it can be chosen as $x^* = [0,...1,0,...0]$ with $1$ at column of $(I+A)^{-1}$ with max $L_1$ norm. Let $x^* = e_j$ with $1$ at $j^{th}$ position.
Hence
$$||(I+A)^{-1}x^*||_2 ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1 \leq 1.$$
$$||(I+A)^{-1}e_j||_2 ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1 \leq 1.$$
$$\lambda_{\min}((I+A)^{-1}) ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1 \leq 1.$$
$$\frac{1}{\lambda_{\max}((I+A))} ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1 \leq 1.$$
$$ ||(I+A)^{-1}||_1 \leq \lambda_{\max}((I+A)).$$
Hence uniformly bounded. Hence proved.

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe this is correct. I'm wondering if we can still bound $\|(I+A)^{-1}\|$ when $\|A\|_1=1$ or $\|A^{-1}\|_1 = 1$ by placing limitations on matrix $A$, such as requiring it to be positive definite?

Comment: @YuanFang updated my answer for Symmetric matrices in $L_2$ norm. Good Luck ! Let me know if you do not agree.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks! I'm curious, though - what happens in the $L_1$ norm? Is it possible to bound $\|(I+A)^{-1}\|_1$ if $\|A\|_1=1$ or $\|A^{-1}\|_1=1$?

Comment: Apologies, I've just noticed a mistake. It appears that we cannot ensure $\|A^{-1}\| < 1$ when $\|A\| > 1.$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, It works only when matrix $A$ satisfies, $||A||>1 \iff ||A^{-1}|| <1$ and viceversa

Comment: @YuanFang updated my answer. Atleast i think we solved it for $||A^{-1}||_1$ bounded away from $1$ now in the above edited answer Please let me know if you agree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145212/discussion-between-yuan-fang-and-balaji-sb).

Comment: Updated the answer. See if its useful.

Comment: I think i solved the problem in attempt 4 above. Edited it. Please check and tell me if you agree. Sorry if there is a mistake again. Pls scrutinize. Good Luck !

Comment: @GoldenSilence Is this answer correct ?

Comment: @Balaji sb Thank you once again for your help. However, I am uncertain as it seems that $\|z\|_1 = \|(I+A)^{-1}x\|_1 \neq 1$

Comment: I  think that Balaji is right. There were a few typos that had my head spinning, but finally managed to understand his proof. Very clever!